# __library_projects__ is missing in Cross-platform Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I am having an error when building a project from a template in Cross-platform in Visual Studio in Xamarin:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at
>   http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "C:\Users\jeric\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Tutorial\DevConStart\DevConStart\DevConStart.Droid\obj\Debug__library_projects__\"
>   is denied.    DevConStart.Droid   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets  974

In case you want to comment in Bugzilla, here is the link: Bug 41095 - **library_projects** is not created and DotNetZip-ewrwre.tmp is missing

so if I manually created a directory **library_projects**, DotNetZip-faasdsd.tmp access denied is having an error when deploying the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is resolved by updating the xamarin and using shortcuts for the SDK path in VS